# Why my file type isn't showing properly?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

I have been reading several posts in stack overflow regarding to the topic of saving and opening files.
But, I couldn't yet solve it.
And my problem is that one :
 Is it normal that my panel doesn't highlight a certain type file properly (without the gray light which means that it isn't considered)
Example:
[image: .asm is in gray light]

.asm should be darker than the others files in this example.

I have been testing several tests and none have been worked yet.

```
public Mips() throws IOException {
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    //fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    //fc.showOpenDialog(fc);


    //FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter(".asm",".asm",".asm");

    //fc.setFileFilter(filter);

    fc.setFileFilter(new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File f) {
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                return true;
            }
            final String name = f.getName();
            return name.endsWith(".asm");
        }

        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "*.asm";
        }
    });

    //fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    fc.showSaveDialog(fc);

    File f = fc.getSelectedFile();
    //String newfile = f + "/mips.asm";
    String newfile = f+".asm";
    System.out.println(newfile);

    try {

    }catch (Exception e){

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you exactly needs? How to retrieve the information of the file, I mean, each line?

Comment: If think you shouldn't pass `fc` as its own parent (but that has nothing to do with your problem). What does it look like when you replace `fc.showSaveDialog(null);` with `showDialog(null, "Save")`?

Comment: Basically, in MacOS X, that's what users expect to see in a **Save** dialog, as you are not supposed to choose a file in it, just to choose a folder and give your file name yourself. So regular files are only blacked in an **Open** dialog where you are supposed to choose a file.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a save dialog!!!

`fc.showSaveDialog(fc);`

There you can choose just folders and specify the filename to save (that is the reason why *all* files appear in grey). For opening files, use

`JFileChooser.showOpenDialog`

Comment: I knew about that.
Just i didn't understand about why a file with .asm wasn't darker than others ! Thankfully to @Axel, now the problem is solved ! :)